# C++ Builder XE7: Using TChart in packages

Tags: c++, c++builder, teechart, c++builder-xe7

I am confronted with a weird situation and I couldn't find any informations about this yet.

I have postet this issue allready on the new Embarcadero community forum but I'm not very hopeful that I will get an answer there... So I decided to create a new account here.

http://community.embarcadero.com/index.php/forum/tools/336-c-builder-xe7-and-teechart-standard)

I use the TChart component which is shiped with the IDE of XE7 (like in older versions). When I
 use it in a package (.dll or .bpl) I get an access violation when I dynamically load, unload, and reload (reloading is the problem) the package wich contains a form with a chart in it. I looked at the loaded packages with a process monitoring tool and everything seems to be allright. The Tee9210.bpl is loaded successfully. When compiling the projects with /XE6 this error doesn't occur.

I could reproduce this on a second environement so I don't think its an issue of my installation/pc.

Can anybody reproduce this? I could provide a test project if needed.

Thank you in advance.

Kerem

**Edit:**
Access Violation when loading the bpl the second time:

Exception class: $C0000005
Message: 'access violation at 0xeeffeeff: access of address 0xeeffeeff'

I noticed that when I try to load the bpl again after this message I get a different exception:

Exception class: $C0000005
Message: 'access violation at 0x503230cf: read of address 0x00000000'

Comment: You'll need to [edit] your post to include a minimal test project here. You'll also need to provide the details of the AV you're getting (the *specific error message*, including any address information).

Comment: I have to look, if I get the permission to upload files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for posting the same question on two pages, but I wasn't sure if the new embarcadero
forum is popular enough to expect an answer from there.

But fortunately Yeray from Steema is active there, too. And I hope the solution could be read on the following link soon.

http://community.embarcadero.com/index.php/forum/tools/336-c-builder-xe7-and-teechart-standard

Comment: We'd ask anybody else experiencing this problem to contact Steema at info@steema.com to get track of the customers affected so we can study the alternatives we have to provide a fix for the problem.